# Create 4 (On and off) buttons, each to modify a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create 4 buttons, each to modify a paragraph. Each button should turn on or off the changes to the paragraph on each click of the button. 
1. Toggle bold button should bold the paragraph.
2. Toggle position should change the position of the paragraph
3. Toggle color will change the color
4. Toggle size will change the size.

My code till now:`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to bold the text of the DIV element:</p>

<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Bold</button></p>

<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.innerHTML === "Hello") {
        x.innerHTML = ;
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Hello";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, here I do not know how to change the paragraph text to bold in this. Moreover, I have to use the event handler for 4 buttons. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the button to toggle the bold-ness of the paragraph by toggling the `font-weight` style.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var div = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (div.style['font-weight']) {
      div.style.removeProperty('font-weight');
    } else {
      div.style['font-weight'] = 800;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to bold the text of the DIV element:</p>

<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Bold</button></p>

<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the handling of four buttons with one function part you can do something like this.
as you create four buttons for each paragraph. modify the onclick event like

```
<p><button onclick="myFunction('myDiv')">Toggle Bold</button></p>
```

Here you are passing the ID of the paragraph controlled by the given button to the function
and modify the event handler with a div paramter like

```js
function myFunction(asdf) {
         var x = document.getElementById(asdf);
         ----your function----
    }
```